# Hyperlink Function using variables

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

I am working on getting a code that both exports PDF's and creates hyperlinks to them. In short I will have multiple sheets. One of them will be a link to the PDF version of the other sheets.

I am working on creating the hyperlinks but I am having errors Every guide I see uses fixed values for creating hyperlinks SO my attempts to make them using variables have all been failing.

Here is the code I have tried. The commented out section was my first attempt and the with loop is my second.

EDIT: The first attempt fills the cell with =hyperlink(CONCATENATE(link.value,own.value),own.value) and not the values. 
The second attempt

The second attempt is a Run-time error '1004':
application-defined or object-defined error highlighting

```
                    .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=main, _
                    Address:=Worksheets("Control Sheet").Range("a1").Value, _
                    TestToDisplay:=own
```

Section of the code.

The value for control sheet a1 is C:\Users\BRL\Desktop\doc approval sheet\File import test\
currently this is where I am testing the file. But I plan on moving this to our directory when I have it locked down. 
I didnt want to complicate it more till i got it working but it will need to be 
C:\Users\BRL\Desktop\doc approval sheet\File import test**own****own.value.pdf**

own is the name of the sheet that will be exported as a PDF(Havent hammered that out yet)

```
Sub Makenewsheet(own As Range)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Sheets("Template").Select
    Sheets("Template").Copy After:=Sheets(4)
    ActiveSheet.NAME = own.Value
    Worksheets("Main Page").Activate
    Dim link As String
    link = Worksheets("Control Sheet").Cells(1, 1).Value
    MsgBox link
    Dim mainpage As Range
    Dim main As Range
    Set mainpage = Worksheets("Main Page").Range("a5:a22")
        For Each main In mainpage
            If IsEmpty(main) = True Then
            'main.Formula = "=hyperlink(CONCATENATE(link.value,own.value),own.value)"
                With Worksheets(1)
                    .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=main, _
                    Address:=Worksheets("Control Sheet").Range("a1").Value, _
                    TestToDisplay:=own
                End With
            GoTo maingame:
            End If
        Next main

maingame:
    Worksheets("Control Sheet").Activate


    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: What's a sample value for `Worksheets("Control Sheet").Range("a1").Value`?

Comment: I don't think if that is your problem but `TestToDisplay:=own` doesn't feel right, shouldn't be `TeXtToDisplay` with an X?

Comment: "I am having errors" is not a very useful description of the exact problem you're having, or where it occurs in your code.

Answer (score 0):

There were two issues in the code, first found above, text not test. But the correct one was 
texttodisplay:=own.value